# Understanding the Rascal support for Java

Tags: rascal

Is it possible to parse Java files that are external to the eclipse environment? I have only realised operations related to obtaining an AST(s) from Eclipse file (or projects).

Does the current version of Rascal support Java 8?

Answer (score 2):

Yes to the first question:

- you could use `lang::java::m3::Core::createM3FromDirectory`, or read its definition and make your own version.
- this code uses `setEnvironmentOptions` to the JDT's Java compiler for controlling the classpath and the sourcepath of the compiler.
- there is no dependency on Eclipse as a whole

To the second question:

- No: the current stable release is pre Java 8
- Yes: the current [unstable release](http://www.rascal-mpl.org/developers/) should work for Java 8. There are no specific tests for this yet, so you may be in for some early adopter surprises.

Comment: I never heard of Rascal till today (used Xtext in the past). Looks interesting.